# SQL - recurring holiday period on a yearly basis

Tags: sql, time, calendar, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Every year specific holiday occurs in my country which lasts 46 days.
I'm working on a code that will return range of dates of that holiday for each year.

Starting point is begining of 'easter' from which I subtract 46 days.

Currently code allows me to distinguis desired period for only one year

```
SELECT * FROM TIME_DIM 

WHERE DATE BETWEEN (SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(day, -46, DATE) as DATE FROM TIME_DIM 
                    WHERE HOLIDAY = 'EASTER' ORDER BY DATE) 
               AND (SELECT TOP 1 DATE FROM TIME_DIM 
                    WHERE HOLIDAY = 'EASTER' ORDER BY DATE ORDER BY DATA)

ORDER BY DATA
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific functions used there...)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, that is on 'snowflake' dwh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Join between' did the trick as well:

```
`SELECT B.DATE AS DATE 
FROM TIME_DIM A 

JOIN TIME_DIM B 
    ON B.DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -46, A.DATE) AND DATEADD(day, -1,A.DATA)

WHERE A.HOLIDAY_NAME = 'Easter'
ORDER BY B.DATA`
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
With HolidayCte as (
Select Year,  date as 'Easter',Dateadd(dd,-46,date) as HolidayStarts
from Time_Dim
Where td.Holiday = 'Easter'
)

Select td.*
from Time_Dim td
join HolidayCte hc on hc.Year = td.year and td.Date between hc.HolidayStarts and hc.Easter
```